# How come using System.Data.Entity needs referencing only Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, namespaces

I've noticed that by installing the Entity Framework NuGet package, three references are added to the project:

- EntityFramework
- EntityFramework.SqlServer
- System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Then I can use `System.Data.Entity` without having it referenced in my project. How is it possible? And how can I implement it in my own works?

By the way, I also looked at source code provided by Microsoft, and made sure that the assembly name is `System.Data.Entity` too:

[System.Data.Entity.csproj](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System.Data.Entity.csproj)

Comment: With what goal? What is your problem?

Comment: @Aldert It's not a problem actually, it's a matter of learning how .NET works. And of course I can take advantages of these techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can use System.Data.Entity without having it referenced in my project. How is it possible?

System.Data.Entity is a namespace.

EntityFramework.dll contains many types that belong to the System.Data.Entity namespace.  EG DbContext.

[DbContext Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx)

> Namespace:   System.Data.Entity
>
> Assembly:  EntityFramework (in
> EntityFramework.dll)

There is an assembly called System.Data.Entity.dll in the .NET Framework, but EF no longer uses it.  EF originally was part of the .NET Framework itself, but is now is shipped through NuGet.  The old support for older versions of EF is *still* part of the .NET Framework, as older applications, using older EF still need it.  See:

> In previous versions of EF the code was split between core libraries
> (primarily System.Data.Entity.dll) shipped as part of the .NET
> Framework and out-of-band (OOB) libraries (primarily
> EntityFramework.dll) shipped in a NuGet package. EF6 takes the code
> from the core libraries and incorporates it into the OOB libraries.
> This was necessary in order to allow EF to be made open source and for
> it to be able to evolve at a different pace from .NET Framework. The
> consequence of this is that applications will need to be rebuilt
> against the moved types.

[Upgrading to Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/upgrading-to-ef6)

Comment: Aha, so `System.Data.Entity` is a namespace within `EntityFramework` assembly (in **EF 6**)! Thanks a lot. It really helped.

Comment: Namespaces and assemblies are not many-to-many.  An assembly can contain classes in multiple namespaces, and a Namespace can have classes across multiple assemblies.